# CSS Selector applied to HTML Page body element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, document-body

I have 4 different pages (Page A, B, C, D) and css code

```
body{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

lets say if I want page B to have a different margin (margin-top:20px;) then how do I place that in the css file.

like maybe something like the following would be pretty cool.

```
@pagename.body{
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Give the body of each page an id / class?

Comment: cant, its in my header.. I can just take it out my header lol but was just trying to see if there is a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this goal, add the following to your HTML:

```
<body id="pagename">
```

and modify CSS correspondingly:

```
body#pagename{
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

If the same styling applies to many pages, you may use `class` instead of `id`:

HTML

```
<body class="pagename">
```

CSS

```
body.pagename{
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

Notice that the use of HTML `body` tag in CSS selector is optional: you can use just `#pagename` instead of `body#pagename`, or `.pagename` instead of `body.pagename`.

Also, below is a sample of direct styling of page `body` element, which provides the most compact styling syntax (pertinent to your CSS sample):

```
<body style="margin-top:20px;">
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: yea I know I can do it this way. only problem is that my body is in my header file as opposed to the individual files..

Comment: Frankly, I don't quite understand what do you mean by "body is in my header file as opposed to the individual files". I've extended my answer with another option. Hope it may help. Best regards,

Comment: sorry for that, my <body> tag is inside my header file. my header file is a file that is called on all my pages. It has a nav bar and thats why its in the header file

Comment: for example, look at James Wright's comment.. my header.php is similar to that.. and its used on every page.. but I just want <body> to be different on one page...

Comment: In this case I would recommend to accept this answer which provides the comprehensive solution to your original question, and if you have more questions reflecting some additional business logic, please post it separately with maximum possible clarity. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Since your header file is a PHP file you can still program it to add a different body class depending on the page that is being served @Bhavik P. though how you do that will be a separate question entirely.

Comment: I agree with @BoltClock : any additional business logic/coding technique questions (PHP header file processing, etc) should be posted separately. Comments thread already became quite lengthy, so let's wrap it up. Best regards,

Comment: yea I figured it out that I could just set a pagename in each page then dynamically set that as an id on my headers... Thanks to all and Alex I'll vote your answers up since my question was very ambiguous. I appreciate the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body class="myBodyClass">
```

CSS:

```
.myBodyClass { margin-top: 20px; }
```

I wouldn't use `body.myBodyClass` since that would be sorta "overqualifying", just choose some sensibly named class, ie do not name it "extraMargin" but rather "certainPageType" (whatever type the page is) in case you want to style more than just an extra margin in the future.

Comment: Ups just saw the answer above, but this is not correct. So `body .pagename` wouldn't work anyways. And since there is only one body tag per page you can also use IDs, but I would stick with a class here.

Comment: Why would you stick with class over id?

Comment: Well mostly a convention. I (almost) always use classNames. Advantage of classNames is that they are reusable, in case you actually prefer something like `.extraMargin`, and want to apply that certain style also with another tag. I use IDs mostly when I have to access them via JS, and of course if the element is unique. In this case it is also quite OK to use an ID.